# Bypass Vertica ERROR 3326: Execution time exceeded run time cap of 01:00?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, oledb, sql-server-data-tools, vertica

Using the `SSIS` tool and `OLE DB`, We are downloading data from a Vertica database, and the time it takes to download all the data exceeds the 1-hour `Execution time exceeded run time cap` set by Vertica.

Is it possible to somehow bypass that cap in SSIS? Maybe close the connection and reopen?

Comment: Interesting.  While I never heard of SISS and am not using OLE DB, I am running into the `Execution time exceeded run time cap` with the command line vsql.  The problem happens to have the same solution, which works at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

`RUNTIMECAP` is a parameter that is active for the duration of a Vertica session.

It can be set through the resource pool you are running under. The Administrator of Vertica can grant a resource pool to your user and configure your user to run under that resource pool. Find out if that is the case for you, and ask the Vertica database administrator to give you a higher runtime cap for exactly the extraction process, if that is the case.

Another way to set the runtime cap is a command that is fired at login (often configured in our OLE DB or ODBC data source configuration) as having to be fired at login:
`SET SESSION RUNTIMECAP '1 HOUR';`

If that's the case, try firing:
`SET SESSION RUNTIMECAP '3 hours';`
... or as much as you need - before running your export.